# How to undo a \def (i.e., Need a \undef capability)

Tags: macros

I thought the way to undo a `\def` was to define it to `\relax`, but that does not appear to work.  Also, am not sure why this produces no output if I try to use `\def` instead of `\let` in my attempt to do an undef.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\CaseA{}%

\ifdefined\CaseA%
    \def\ProcessCaseA{}%
    % Do stuff that uses \ProcessCaseA
    %\def\ProcessCaseA\relax% no output if use this, and comment next line
    \let\ProcessCaseA\relax% no output if comment this, and use above line
\fi

% Now do stuff that requires \ProcessCaseA NOT be defined
\ifdefined\ProcessCaseA
    ERROR: \textbackslash ProcessCaseA is still defined
\else
    SUCCESS: \textbackslash ProcessCaseA is not defined
\fi

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The macro `\ifdefined` is not part of basic TeX, so I suppose you are getting it from eTeX.  In that case, you should consider using the `etoolbox` package, which provides a few wrapper functions `\ifdef{\macro}{true}{false}` and `\ifundef{\macro}{true}{false}`.  The etoolbox manual tells me that the latter has the convenient effect of registering a macro `\let` to `\relax` as being "undefined", which sounds like what you want.

Alternatively, depending on the situation, if you truly wish to erase a macro from TeX's memory, you can define it in a group and then leave the group.  Note that this is quite different from `\let`ting it to `\relax`, since if TeX tries to read `\macro` before it has ever been `\def`'d or `\let`, it will raise an error, while if you have written `\let\macro=\relax`, it will just do nothing.

Comment: Adding `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` worked great. Thanks.

Comment: `etoolbox` also has `\undef`.

Comment: @Philipp: so it does!  I never went to that section of the manual.

Comment: @RyanReich Could you update your answer including an example of the use of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`? I understand the spirit, but I'm having problems implementing it! Thank you.

Comment: Note, the "define in group then leave group" solution as far as I can see only works when the *original* definition can be moved inside a group. If it's already defined globally/in the current level, no amount of group manipulating can undefine it. //

Answer (score 34):

You need to let it to undefined, not relax, try this

```
\providecommand*\@nameundef[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\@undefined}
```

See comments by Ulrich below for some caveats.

Comment: ... conditional on the fact that no control sequence named `\@undefined` is defined. (But I think that's assumed at some places in the kernel as well, so \def\@undefined{} would likely break a lot of stuff anyway, so the user will notice.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz The command `\@undefined` is used more than 800 times in my texmf tree, so it is a good assumption.

Answer (score 26):

The assignment `\let\xyz\relax` makes `\xyz` "undefined" as far as the `\@ifundefined` test is concerned. So

```
\makeatletter
\let\xyz\relax
\@ifundefined{xyz}{LaTeX undefined}{LaTeX defined}\par
\ifdefined\xyz e-TeX defined\else e-TeX undefined\fi\par
\ifcsname xyz\endcsname e-TeX defined\else e-TeX undefined\fi\par
```

would print

> LaTeX undefined
>   e-TeX defined
>   e-TeX defined

The only safe way to "undefine" a command is to define it inside a group: at the end of it the definition will vanish. There is `\undef` in **etoolbox** that relies on the fact that a specific control sequence (`\etb@undefined`) will never be defined by anybody.

Choosing between the `\@ifundefined` and `\ifdefined` tests is a matter of convenience and mostly depends on what you need. Notice that the argument to `\@ifundefined` is the macro's *name*, without the backslash.

Comment: @tohecz It undefines the command, unless `\@undefined` has received a meaning. It's the same as `etoolbox`'s `\undef`.

Comment: Is there a latex3 equivalent? If I have for example `\l_prefix_foo_skip` as [in your answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172267/4990).

Comment: @Grimler Why would you want to undefine a register name?