# undefining custom commands

Tags: macros

After you define a command using `\newcommand`, is it possible to undefine it?

My motivation is that I'm writing a thesis, where each chapter is in a separate source file. Some chapters define their own commands that are used nowhere else, so I'd like them to be visible only within that chapter.

I'd therefore like to be able to do something like:

```
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\newcommand{foo}{...}
... % chapter body
\forgetcommand{foo}
% end of chapter
```

Is there anything like the fictitious `\forgetcommand` macro above?

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20655/how-to-undo-a-def-i-e-need-a-undef-capability, this appears like a duplicate question.

Comment: It should also work to use `\let\foo\undefined`.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: If I were familiar with raw TeX, I'd probably be able to parse that question you linked to, and its answer. Unfortunately I've only ever dealt with the subset of LaTeX needed to write scientific papers. I suspect I'm not alone.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks, that worked. If you post that as an answer, I'll choose it.

Comment: @SuperElectric: I've done so. Also see the other approach I provide via `\providecommand` - it seems to be more in line with what you may be after.

Comment: I really don't understand why nobody has mentioned `\undef\foo`. For some reason, I cannot add an answer, just comments.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If your concern is whether or not a command exists and you want to define/redefine it, LaTeX provides `\providecommand` which has a similar interface as `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`. It does the appropriate (re)definition where necessary.

Alternatively, if you want to "undefine" a command `\foo`, you could also just use `\let\foo\undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. FWIW, I much prefer your \let\foo\undefined option over using \providecommand. The latter leaves open the possibility that I'll define \foo in chapter1, forget to redefine it in chapter 2, then invoke it in chapter 2, expecting its chapter-2-specific definition which I forgot to provide. With \let\foo\undefined, this mistake would be caught by the compiler.

Comment: It should be noted that `\undefined` does not have a special meaning here, but it is simply assumed that it is not defined. `\let` copies every aspect of a control sequence including its undefinedness. So `\let\foo\anymacrowhichisnotdefined` will also work. This of course breaks if any code before defines that macro, Often a `\@undefined` is used inside packages, to lower that risk a little.

Comment: @MartinScharrer thanks for your comment. I've since come across the variant `\let\foo\relax` and from what I can tell it's perfect as it avoids the issue you mention, or does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: @lukeuser: Consider [this example code](https://pastebin.com/raw/pxG3H5Xc). Using `\ifcsname <csname> \endcsname` you get expected results if `<csname>` is not defined. However, since `\relax` is defined, `\let\<csname>\relax` does follow a different conditional branch under `\ifcsname ... \endcsname`. In contrast, `\@ifundefined{<csname>}{<undefined>}{<defined>}` does an extra check to see whether it's defined as `\relax`.

Comment: @Werner many thanks for this info and explanation! This is all really interesting (and has helped me get a better understanding of tex).

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following example. It shows the way as Seamus suggested and the way with `\let...\undefined`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\foo}{Foo}
\newcommand{\baz}{Baz}

\begin{document}
x\foo\baz x

\renewcommand{\foo}{}
\let\baz\undefined

x\foo%
%\baz x% can’t use \baz anymore

%\newcommand{\foo}{FOO}% doesn?t work
\renewcommand{\foo}{FOO}% still need \renew...
\newcommand{\baz}{BAZ}

x\foo\baz x
\end{document}
```

`\foo` dosen’t produce an output anymore but can’t be defined a second time (it still needs the `\renew…` command). `\baz` is removed an can be defined a second time.

Comment: I'd `\let` to `\undefined`, as that was the request here (`\relax` is not the same thing).

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks. I thougt there would be a better way, but didn’t know it yet. I used `\let…\relax` in the past and it worked fine till now. I’ll change my example.

Answer (score 2):

If the macro is used nowhere else, there's no problem leaving it defined surely.

Rather than encapsulation, you could consider name-spacing your chapter specific macros.

So macros used only in chapter one look like this: `\chaponefoo…` while macros from chapter three will be: `\chapthreefoo…` and so on.

(My previous answer had some problems, and Werner's answer is better.)

Comment: The latter will gobble arguments if the same macro was used in subsequent chapters, rather than doing nothing or producing an error.

Comment: When defining a command in a chapter, I currently need to check previous chapters to see if it's been already defined differently. If it is, I must use \renewcommand. If it isn't, I must use \newcommand. I don't want to have to worry about this, so I want a chapter-specific command to be forgotten entirely at the end of its chapter. Consider this desire for encapsulation a programmer's itch.

Comment: @SuperElectric: You can do that with a combination of `\providecommand{\foo}{}` and `\renewcommand{\foo}<etc>`

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: See my comment to Werner's answer for why I prefer \let\foo\undefined (it makes the compiler catch my mistakes).