# fancyhdr and memoir

Tags: header-footer, memoir, fancyhdr

When I wrote the code below gave the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \footruleskip already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.302 ...and{\footruleskip}{.3\normalbaselineskip}
```

I want to configure the `fancyhdr` on `memoir`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% fancyhdr on memoir
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\space#1}}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{R\'egis \the\year}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Fancyhdr on Memoir}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the [memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class has its own mechanism for headers and footers, there is no need to use the [fancyhdr](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package. Just check out Section 7.3 of the class manual.

Answer (score 20):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) defined the command `\footruleskip` as

```
\newcommand{\footruleskip}{0.3\normalbaselineskip}
```

while [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) does the same

```
\newcommand{\footruleskip}{.3\normalbaselineskip}
```

(something done since May 7, 1996 with version 1.99 of `fancyhdr` - a change from a former length `\footruleskip` to the current control sequence). The good thing is that they're both the same. So, undefining it before loading `fancyhdr` works:

```
%...
\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
%...
```

Here `\undefined` is an undefined control sequence that might just as well have been `\bleepbloopblah` (...as long as that is undefined as well!). See, for example [How to undo a \def (i.e., Need a \undef capability)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20655/how-to-undo-a-def-i-e-need-a-undef-capability) and [undefining custom commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35962/undefining-custom-commands).

Although this is your choice, `memoir` as a solid document class provides ample page header style modifications, and is therefore on the same footing as `fancyhdr`. Therefore, you may find some conflicting support if using `fancyhdr` instead of `memoir` header/footer functionality. Read up on what `memoir` is capable of in chapter **7 Pagination and headers** (p 117) of the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf). In fact, the documentation mentions (in section **7.2 Page styles**, p 118):

> These facilities were inspired by the `fancyhdr` package [..],
>   although the command set is different.

Comment: Plus in `memoir` the headers and footers a much more integrated, than `fancyhdr` will ever be. For example the `\chapter` title pages make use of a build in style called `chapter` (an alias for `plain`) and can easily be changed into something else, independently of what `plain` does