# Is it possible to use 12 pt font size in the achemso package?

Tags: fontsize, achemso

I am typesetting a report using the `achemso` [package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso), because it is required that my report be in American Chemical Society (ACS) format. However, I am *not* submitting to an ACS journal.  It is required that my report be in 12 pt Times New Roman font with 1.5 line spacing.  I think that `achemso` by default uses Times New Roman (that is what it looks like), and I can accomplish 1.5 line spacing with `\onehalfspacing`.

How can I accomplish 12 pt font size in `achemso`?  I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{achemso}
```

But I get this warning/error:

> LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
>       [12pt].

Is there any way I can still use `achemso` and enforce 12 pt font size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a word, 'no'. The `achemso` *class* is intended purely to support submissions to the ACS, and so has no features which are not needed for that purpose. The `achemso` *package* is intended to support producing more general documents which need some of the features of the class. You should use a suitable general class (for example `report`) and load appropriate packages.

Comment: The real reason I am using `achemso` even though I am not submitting to the ACS is that `achemso` provides the correct bibliography formatting for use with my bibtex files; `achemso` correctly formats the citations, as well as uses the in-line superscript citation notation.  I am worried that if I abandon `achemso`, it will be harder to use the superscript citation notation.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?  Thank you!

Comment: The `achemso` package does the same set up as the class for the bibliography, so just `\usepackage{achemso}` should cover it.

Answer (score 3):

As of today, achemso's main font size *is* 12 pt. Quote from its source (https://github.com/josephwright/achemso/blob/master/achemso.dtx#L968):

```
\LoadClass[12pt,letter]{article}
```

Nevertheless, what you are asking for in general seems to be easily achievable. I wanted to use the achemso class (but not for ACS submission) and change the main font size (from 12 pt to 11 pt). This is what works well:

```
\let\titlefont\undefined
\makeatletter
\let\l@addto@macro\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage[fontsize=11pt]{scrextend}
```

This solution is a combination of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5341/11816 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35967/11816  -- without the undefinition of \titlefont, there is a clash between KOMA `titlefont` and achemso `titlefont`.

I'm interested to hear about disadvantages with this approach.

Comment: Sounds a bit like *von hinten durch die Brust ins Auge* to be honest.

Comment: @Johannes_B: sure. Application scenario: submission to a different non-ACS journal which *only* requires an 11 pt font size. Other than that, `achemso` fits perfectly fine. So, in that case, I'd say this is a viable option.

Comment: The line `\let\l@addto@macro\relax` does ***nothing at all*** in this case, because `scrextend` uses it in the code for `\deffootnote`. Actually, if `\deffootnote` gets used for some reason, that line would break it.

Answer (score 0):

The default font size of `achemso` is 12pt

```
\documentclass{achemso}

\title{Title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\affiliation{Some University}
\email{a.uthor@someuniversity.edu}

\begin{document}

\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

If you want to use a different point size, you can use `fontsize` that has no dependencies, contrary to `scrextend`.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % for scalable Computer Modern
\documentclass{achemso}
\usepackage[fontsize=11pt]{fontsize}

\title{Title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\affiliation{Some University}
\email{a.uthor@someuniversity.edu}

\begin{document}

\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

[image]