# Use of \l@addto@macro

Tags: macros

I am trying to change the font size of the achemso document class, and I came across this snippet of code on the second answer here: [Is it possible to use 12 pt font size in the achemso package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60029/is-it-possible-to-use-12-pt-font-size-in-the-achemso-package)

```
\let\titlefont\undefined
\makeatletter
\let\l@addto@macro\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage[fontsize=10pt]{scrextend}
```

It accomplishes the goal just fine, but I want to understand what the various lines are doing. I get that `\let\titlefont\undefined` is un-defining the title font of KOMA-script to avoid clash with achemso. I'm also okay with the `\makeatletter \makeatother` lines and the `\usepackage` line. But what is the `\let\l@addto@macro\relax` line doing? It seems to work with or without it. I tried researching `\l@addto@macro`, but all I could find is information on `\g@addto@macro`; what's the difference?

Comment: Normally `\g@addto@macro` changes the definition of the macro globally, while `\l@addto@macro` does so locally. Usage looks like this `\newcommand\foo{bar}\l@addto@macro\foo{baz}` and then the replacement text of `\foo` is `barbaz`.

Comment: I doubt that the l@addto-line is still needed (and it is unclear if it was ever needed). Leave out. But as said in the other answer: it doesn't make sense to use a class like achemso and to  change it.

Comment: @Skillmon: In the usage above, then, is it adding `\relax` to the `\let` command for just this document (since it was local and not global)? Am I understanding that correctly? Many thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The line definitely seems to not be required. Thanks for confirming. The only reason that I wanted to change the font size was to save paper when printing for my supervisor.

Comment: No, `\let` acts on `\l@addto@macro` turning it into `\relax` (which is roughly as good as undefining it).

Comment: By the way, I doubt very much that such a code would have worked correctly, because `\l@addto@macro` is a macro with two arguments and that redefinition would leave the two arguments in the input stream.

Comment: @egreg I'd guess it was used because `scrextend` defined `\l@addto@macro` with `\newcommand` and was erring because it was already defined.

Comment: @Skillmon I doubt that one would have ever got an error, because `scrextend` uses `\l@addto@macro` only inside the definition of `\deffootnote`. And *doesn't* define it. One gets an error if `\deffootnote` is used, but undefining `\l@addto@macro` is *not* the solution.

Comment: @egreg but `scrextend` requires `scrkbase` which requires `scrbase` which defines `\l@addto@macro` (the current version uses `\def`, but I have no idea whether that's always been the case).

Comment: @Skillmon Did you try without? I did, with TeX Live from 2020 (when `scrextend` was deployed) to 2023.

Comment: @egreg as I said I didn't check the history. In the meantime I looked at TL2018's `scrbase` and there it was already a `\def` plus a check if it's defined whether the meaning matches what KOMA expects. So all this `\let`-code ever could've done was throw a warning that KOMA redefines it because the meaning of `\l@addto@macro` is wrong... Indeed not that useful :)

Answer (score 1):

That code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is wrong and should be used nowhere.

If you try without that line, you'll see no difference at all.

The komascript classes and packages use `\l@addto@macro` in a few places. In `scrextend.sty` it's used once:

```
\newcommand\deffootnote[4][]{%
  \expandafter\ifnum\scr@v@is@ge{3.22}\relax
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
      \ExecuteDoHook{footnote/text/begin}%
      \raggedfootnote
      \leftskip #2
      \l@addto@macro\@trivlist{%
        \ifnum\@listdepth=\@ne\advance\leftmargin #2\relax\fi
      }%
      \parindent #3\noindent
  [...code not relevant...]
}
```

The macro is supposed to take two arguments and making it equivalent to `\relax` would leave those arguments in the input stream as soon as `\deffootnote` is used and later a footnote is processed, so executing `\@trivlist` at an unexpected and wrong place. For completeness of description, the second argument would do nothing, because the assignment would be executed in a group anyway.