# How can I undefine an environment?

Tags: environments

How can I undefine an environment?

This is how to undefine a command:

```
\newcommand\foo
\makeatletter
\let\foo\@undefined
\makeatother
```

I need to undefine the `spacing` environment from the `setspace` package.
This does not seem to work:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter
\let\beginspacing\@undefined
\let\endspacing\@undefined    
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The macro `\newenvironment{foo}` defines the two macros

```
\foo
\endfoo
```

not `\beginfoo`.

Rather than undefine `spacing`, you could simply make it a noop:

```
\renewenvironment{spacing}{}{}
```

This is preferable because it will keep track of nested environments.

Comment: What is an environment needs to be undefined, because it was predefined but conflicts with some package? Is there a better way than going through `\makeatletter`?

Comment: @Alexey Where do you get to undefine the environment?

Comment: In my own class i defined an environment, and then i loaded a package that defines an environment with the same name :). I do not want to change my class, usually it is fine.

Comment: @Alexey It mostly depends on which of the two conflicting definitions you want to keep.

Comment: I wanted to keep the one coming from a package (not mine).

Comment: @Alexey Then say `\let\whatever\relax` and `\let\endwhatever\relax` before loading the package (if the environment is called `whatever`).

Comment: @egreg i want to undefine an environment to make using it produce an error and thereby enforce a policy. i have defined new environments based on this forbidden one and i want only to new ones to be used. the \@undefined approach results in errors using the new ones because they use the forbidden one ... can this be achieved?

Comment: @peter It's better if you ask a new question with the needed details.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35967/153678), use

```
\let\spacing\@undefined
\let\endspacing\@undefined
```

to undefine the `spacing` environment. Note that `\@undefined` is not a special command, it simply is, itself, undefined.