# \DeclarePairedDelimiter with a name that is already defined

Tags: mathtools, physics

How do I introduce a paired delimiter with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`, if the name that I want to use for the delimiter is already declared by some other package?

For example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lvert\lvert}{\rvert\rvert}

\begin{document}
I do not even need to use $\norm{v}$ to have an error.
\end{document}
```

Note that, unlike [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35962/undefining-custom-commands) or [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20655/how-to-undo-a-def-i-e-need-a-undef-capability) I am wondering about overriding an existing macro to make it a paired delimiter within the package `mathttools`, and not how to make a `\newcommand` with a name that has been already defined (in the latter case, I can, for example, `\renewcommand`).

Note that the question is not about how should you typeset a norm operator.

The reason why one may want to redefine a command in `physics` package as a `mathtools`paired delimiter is that a paired delimiter can open and close on two different lines.

Comment: `\let\norm\relax` prior to the declaration.  But be wary of redeclaring standard symbols.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Undefining custom commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35962/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in my comment, one can undeclare a macro, such as `\norm`, with `\let\norm\relax`.  And then, one can declare it as if it did not yet exist.  The admonition is to be careful in redeclaring standard LaTeX (or package-defined) symbols, lest you break something else.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\let\norm\relax
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
I do not even need to use $\norm{v}$ to have an error.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As campa notes, the use of `\lVert` and `\rVert` **IS STRONGLY** preferable to the use of `\lvert\lvert` and `\rvert\rvert`, as in

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
```

I have thus adopted that change in my answer.

Finally, Andrew notes that had `\norm` been defined via `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, this simple method with `\let` would not work, since there is an associated macro also defined.

Comment: `\norm` is not standard LaTeX but defined in the `physics` package.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks.  I made a clarification.

Comment: @campa It would seem that `\lVert ... \rVert` is equivalent to what the `physics` package provides.  Thus, there would be no need to redefine it.  But I will edit to make a note of it.

Comment: I find the space between the two single bars way too large... `\lVert` is not just built out of two `|`, it's a separate glyph

Comment: Also note that had `\norm` been defined via `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, this simple method with `\let` would not work, since there is an associated macro also defined.

Comment: I want `\norm` to be able to span multiple lines, which I do not seem to get from the `physics` package, but I do get by defining it as a `mathtools` paired delimiter.

Comment: Another _strong_ argument against the version with `\lvert\lvert...\rvert\rvert`: try `\norm*{\frac{1}{2}}` in display math, or `$\norm[\Big]{a}$`, and enjoy the result `:-)`

Comment: @campa Revised to heed your advice.