# How to remove the space after an empty note in \autocite?

Tags: macros, biblatex

I am currently writing my thesis, and I would like to put a placeholder for "cf." in my `autocite` like so:

`\autocite[\cf][]{Author.2016}`

Reason: in case my mentor wants me to use a citation style that requires cf., I want to "toggle" the cf. on and off. However, if I define the `\cf` command as empty (`\newcommand{\cf}{}`), the autocite command automatically adds a space in front of the author: ( Schmidt et al. 2013).

Undefining the cf command with `\let\cf\undefined` (as suggested in "[undefining custom commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35962/undefining-custom-commands)") does not work, since the command is, well, undefined :D

Any ideas how to tell LaTeX to just "ignore" `\cf` (or to remove the space after the empty note)?

Thanks!!

EDIT: Working example

document.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\newcommand{\cf}{}

\begin{document}
    This is some text~\autocite[\cf][]{Schmidt.2013}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@book{Schmidt.2013,
 author = {Schmidt},
 year = {2013},
 title = {Some Title}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier to make a suggestion when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nasty trick!

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Schmidt.2013,
 author = {Schmidt},
 year = {2013},
 title = {Some Title}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand\nocfspace{\renewcommand{\prenotedelim}{}}
\newcommand{\cf}{\aftergroup\nocfspace}

\begin{document}

This is some text~\autocite[\cf][]{Schmidt.2013}

This is some other text \autocite[as in][]{Schmidt.2013}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that works! Thank you so much!
Is `\prenotedelim` the space?

Comment: @hbrgnr `\prenotedelim` is what's inserted between the prenote text and the citation.