# make latex take a command from a certain package

Tags: errors, siunitx

I want pdflatex to take the command `\num` from the package `siunitx`, but the command seems to already be defined in the package `stata` obtainable (in complicated ways, if you don't have stata, unfortunately) from http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/texdoc/index.html.
*(I'd provide the whole sty file in a github repo, but I don't know whether the Stata ToS or Ben Jann would allow it, so, sorry about that.)*

### Main question

**How do I tell LaTeX to take the definition of `\num` from `siunitx.sty` without altering `stata.sty`** (like, say, just going ahead and deleting that line in `stata.sty`, which would solve the problem instantly, but I might need that definition later in another document)**?** Other adviceful comments welcome whatsoever.

Here is an MWE, the desired and faulty output:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stata} % <--- deactivate to get desired output
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        P(x \leq 2) & = \num{1e-9} + \num{8.1e-8} 
    \end{align*}

    \num{1e-9}
\end{document}
```

what it *should* look like

[image: desired output equation]

what it *does* look like

[image: current output equation]

the error I get (logfile)

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined"
! 
! Command '\num' already defined!
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.7289 }

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| You have used \NewDocumentCommand with a command that already has a
| definition.
| The existing definition of '\num' will not be altered.
|...............................................
```

and (error list in texstudio)

```
LaTeX error: "xparse/command-already-defined" Command '\num' already defined! For immediate help type H <return>. }
```

the definition of `\num` in `siunitx.sty`

```
\NewDocumentCommand \num { o m } {
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
    \bool_set_false:N \l__siunitx_font_set_bool
    \IfNoValueF {#1}
      { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1} }
    \__siunitx_number_output:n {#2}
  \group_end:
}
```

and the same definition in `stata.sty`

```
\def\num{{\it \#\/}}
```

(*Annotation: I know the command `\it` is deprecated, since I am told so by the program, if I invert the load order ot the packages `stata` and `siunitx`, but that's a different matter I shall need to discuss with Dr. Jann*)

Comment: I don't have `stata.sty` but as a work-around you could put `\let\num\relax` or (maybe better?) `\let\num\undefined` between loading `stata` and `siunitx`.

Comment: or `\let\num\undefined` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35962/undefining-custom-commands.

Comment: You could load `siunitx` first, then `\let\SInum\num` and `\let\num\relax`.  Then, load `stata` package.  Use `\SInum` when you want the `siunitx` version.

Comment: funnily enough, any of those produce the right math syntax in the main document font in my main document, but work in the MWE I provided here. Well, it answers the question, as far as I'm concerned, but now I have another problem and I'm not sure I will be able to pin down this one. Any of you is welcome to write an answer. Personally, I think I prefer the option to still be able to use stata's `\num` command, but inverting the order might produce other, yet unknown, issues down the road.