# Conflict between amsrefs package and the document class of a journal

Tags: journal, amsrefs

The package amsrefs is in conflict with the document class [qt2018author](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/instructions/QT/qt_macros.zip) (of a journal).
I got the following error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \eprint already defined.` I guess the problem comes from the fact that the field `\eprint` should appear in both.

How to solve this problem without removing amsrefs?

---

Below is a simple example where the problem appears:

```
\documentclass{qt2018author}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{p3}{article}{
   author={Palcoux, Sebastien},
   title={Euler totient of subfactor planar algebras},
   journal={Proc. Am. Math. Soc.}
   volume={146},
   number={11},
   date={2018},
   pages={4775--4786},
   doi={10.1090/proc/14167}
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \eprint already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.2820 \newcommand{\eprint}[1]{\url{#1}}
```

Comment: OK, the class can be downloaded, but we need an example document for the conflict.

Comment: @egreg: Done! I just added a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `qt2018author` class the `\eprint` command only occurs two times, the first time when it is defined and the second time when it is used in the `\arXiv` command. So you can undefine the command (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35967/), redefine it with a different name, and change the call in the `\arXiv` command. The redefinitions should be performed before you load the `amsrefs` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{qt2018author}
\let\eprint\undefined
\newcommand*{\eprintnew}[2][arXiv]{%
 \ifstrequal{#1}{arXiv}%
  {\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/#2}{arXiv:#2}}%
  {\mbox{#1:#2}}}
\renewcommand*{\arXiv}[1]{\eprintnew[arXiv]{#1}}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{p3}{article}{
   author={Palcoux, Sebastien},
   title={Euler totient of subfactor planar algebras},
   journal={Proc. Am. Math. Soc.},
   volume={146},
   number={11},
   date={2018},
   pages={4775--4786},
   doi={10.1090/proc/14167}
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that in the original code there was a comma missing in line 12, which triggers the warning `Package rkeyval Warning: Missing comma on input line 13`.

Note also (as explained in the linked question) that when using `\let\eprint\undefined`, the macro `\undefined` is not a special LaTeX command, it is just something that does not exist (`\let\eprint\foo` would also work). This is sufficient to bypass the check for commands being already defined, which causes the error message that you encountered.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Now, what is the point of redefining it (amsrefs will do the job)?

Comment: The point is that the two definitions are different, in `amsrefs` the definition is just `\url{#1}` instead of the more complex definition from `qt2018author` which has two arguments and the special formatting for arXiv. Therefore, if you use two arguments for `\eprint` or you use the `\arXiv` command then you need the redefinition. If you don't use that at all then you don't need the redefinition.