# make command undefined

Tags: programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to undo a \def (i.e., Need a \undef capability)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20655/how-to-undo-a-def-i-e-need-a-undef-capability)

In my template I test for chapter defined to prevent that code section only valid for a chapter class are executed. However if I load `titlesec` chapter is always defined regardless of the class in use.

So how can I make `\chapter` undefined after the execution of titlesec?

So far I tried this which did not work:

```
 \ifcsdef{chapter}{%
   \usepackage{titlesec}%
   % make chapter undefined again
   \let\chapter\relax%
 }{
   \usepackage{titlesec}%
 }
```

Comment: What happens if you `\let\chapter\UnDeFiNED` instead of `\relax`?

Comment: `\undef\chapter` seems to work with `etoolbox` package.  Test case:`Chapter is \ifcsdef{chapter}{defined}{undefined}.`  And @Marco's suggestion also works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting `\chapter` to `\relax`, you can set it to an undefined sequence:

```
\let\chapter\undefined
```

Comment: I use now `\undef\chapter` instead, but both work.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech `\undef\chapter` does a similar thing, precisely `\let\chapter\etb@undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick, it keeps the definition of `\chapter` (defined or undefined) that was active before package `titlesec` is loaded:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\saved@chapter}{%
  \let\saved@chapter\chapter
  \usepackage{titlesec}%
  \let\chapter\saved@chapter
}
\makeatother
```