# Define and set length in one command

Tags: macros, expansion, lengths

Sorry this might be a very simple question, I am trying to cleanup a style file, and would like to write a command that basically runs the following code:

```
\newlength{<name>}\setlength{<name>}{<value>}
```

Based on another command that runs a `\def`, I though I'd be able to use `expandafter` and `csname` easily; here is what I tried:

```
\newcommand{\deflen}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newlength{%
    \csname #1\endcsname}\setlength{%
    \csname #1\endcsname}{#2}
}
```

Unfortunately, this seems to generate an error related to `csname` being already defined. I think it means that I can't use `csname` twice in the same expand, but I don't know how to define the name first, and then use it twice... Help? :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to assemble the control sequence name before defining with `\newcommand`, and before using it. This can be achieved using `\expandafter` twice.

```
\newcommand{\deflen}[2]{%      
    \expandafter\newlength\csname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\setlength\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\deflen{mylength}{12pt}

\showthe\mylength
```

Answer (score 12):

Ian Thompson's code is good, but you could add the check whether you *can* define a new length in the first place; calling, say,

```
\deflen{textwidth}{6pt}
```

would issue an error message at `\newlength`, but it would set `\textwidth` nonetheless. Since you are in a style file you don't need `\makeatletter` for `@` commands, so you can do

```
\newcommand{\deflen}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname{\prefix@deflen{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\prefix@deflen}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newlength\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\setlength\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

The code given as second argument to `\@ifdefinable` is executed only if the control sequence given as first argument is undefined; otherwise an error is raised and the code is ignored.

Note that `prefix` stands for the prefix used in the style file for not clobbering other packages' macros.

A LaTeX3 version could be

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\deflen}{ s m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   { \prefix_deflen:nnn { dim }  { #2 } { #3 } }
   { \prefix_deflen:nnn { skip } { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \prefix_deflen:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { #2 }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { package } { already~defined } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \__prefix_deflen:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__prefix_deflen:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \use:c { #1_new:c } { l_prefix_#2_#1 }
  \use:c { #1_set:cn } { l_prefix_#2_#1 } { #3 }
  \cs_set_eq:cc { #2 } { l_prefix_#2_#1 } % user level name
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { package } { already~defined }
 {
  Control~sequence~\exp_not:c { #1 } already~defined.
 }
 {
  The~control~sequence~\exp_not:c { #1 } already~exists.~
  Please~use~a~new~name;~the~command~will~not~be~executed.
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Note that `\deflen{foo}{6pt}` will define `\l_prefix_foo_skip` as the internal name of the register, but also `\foo` at the user level. The *-version would allocate a rigid length register (a `\dimen`, in TeXspeak).

Test code:

```
\deflen{foo}{3pt}
\showthe\foo
\show\foo

\deflen*{baz}{3pt}
\showthe\baz
\show\baz

\deflen{textwidth}{3pt}
```

Here's the terminal output:

```
> 3.0pt.
l.40 \showthe\foo

? 
> \foo=\skip47.
l.41 \show\foo

? 
> 3.0pt.
l.44 \showthe\baz

? 
> \baz=\dimen133.
l.45 \show\baz

? 

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! package error: "already defined"
! 
! Control sequence \textwidth already defined.
! 
! See the package documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.46 \deflen{textwidth}{3pt}

? h
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| The control sequence \textwidth already exists. Please use a new name; the
| command will not be executed.
|...............................................
?
```

Comment: Your answer is incredible, I didn't even know there was a LaTeX3.. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sh3ljohn There's not yet a LaTeX3, but its programming layer is already usable along with current LaTeX. As you see, there's no visible `\expandafter`. Once one gets the hang of it, programming is really easier.