# file ended while scanning use of \path

Tags: macros, urls, patching

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{xcolor,letltxmacro,booktabs,longtable,tabu}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldpath}{\path}
\renewcommand{\path}[1]{\color{gray}{\oldpath{#1}}}


\begin{document}
    \section{Software Requirements}\label{scn:softreq}
    %
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Windows 8.1 64-bit with .NET framework 3.5
        \item Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional with Service Pack 1
        \item Download and install:
        %
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \texttt{qt-win-opensource-4.8.4-vs2010} from \url{http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.4/qt-win-opensource-4.8.4-vs2010.exe}.
            \item \texttt{qt-creator-windows-opensource-2.6.2} available in \path{C:\Code\Pre-requisite-Setup\}
            \item \texttt{qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource} from  \url{http://download.qt.io/archive/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe}.
            \item \texttt{qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.6.0} from \url{http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.6/5.6.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.6.0.exe}.
        \end{itemize}
        %
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If, instead of `\path{C:\Code\Pre-requisite-Setup\}` I write `\path{C:\Code\Pre-requisite-Setup}`, no errors are encountered. The problem is with `LetLtxMacro` which I have used.

**Error: file ended while scanning use of \path**

The document is too long for me to go back and change each instance.

I have gone through [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself) and could not implement it to modify `path`.

I need help to modify the useless macro and eventually find inner peace.

Comment: "The document is too long for me to go back and change each instance."  Surely any editor will allow you to fix all such cases without much effort no matter how long the document? just globally change `\path{([^{}]*)\}` to `\path{\1}`

Comment: Of course!! Why didn't I think of it? Maybe I was too hung up on fixing `\path`. Thanks :)

Comment: note you should anyway do as mico suggests as apart from the error from `\}` with your redefinition the argument is not read verbatim so you get a space after each "command" `\Code`, `\Pre` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `url.sty` defines `\path` as follows:

```
\@ifundefined{path}{\DeclareUrlCommand\path{\urlstyle{tt}}}{}
```

In constrast, your (re)definition of `\path` does not use the `\DeclareUrlCommand` machinery. That's why it gets hung up on the "`\}`" substring in `\path{C:\Code\Pre-requisite-Setup\}`. (Note also that `\path` -- as defined in the `url` package via `\DeclareUrlCommand` -- doesn't take optional arguments. Hence, using `\LetLtxMacro` achieves nothing that couldn't be handled via `\let`.)

The remedy is to redefine `\path` as follows (in the preamble, after loading the `url` package):

```
\let\path\relax
\DeclareUrlCommand\path{\color{gray}\urlstyle{tt}}
```

*Addendum*: As @egreg has pointed out in a comment, the instruction `\let\path\relax` isn't strictly necessary as the subsequent `\DeclareUrlCommand` instruction overwrites the existing definition of `\path`. Fortunately, `\let\path\relax` doesn't hurt either. :-)

Comment: Can I use this to edit other existing macros like `\emph`, `\texttt` etc? If each macro has different method to redefine it, how can I identify them? Any tell-tale signs?

Comment: Also, I tried to use it with `\longtabu` but failed. `Error: File ended while scanning use of \tabu@collectbody.` For now I have simply removed the offending '\' from the end of paths.

Comment: @manucpp - The definition of `\path` is very special. There's no reason to presume that its setup is of any relevance for other commands such as, say, `\emph` or `\longtabu`. (If you need help with redefining `\longtabu`, you should pose a new question.) Incidentally, is there a reason for not implementing the solution I suggested and, instead, editing all the path strings to remove the trailing backslash characters?

Comment: Please accept my apologies if this was not clear earlier. I implemented your solution and then this error with `longtabu` came up. There were some paths in table --  specifying files, their source and destination --  which had the trailing '/'.

Comment: @manucpp - Thanks. Just to reiterate: The definition of `\path` in the `url` package is very special -- mainly because a URL string or fully qualified path string can contain various characters that may have a "special" meaning for TeX. (One such character, as you've discovered, is the backslash character, "\".) If you need to modify `longtabu`, I suggest you begin by perusing the code of the `longtabu` package.

Comment: Code is something, I do not understand much -- having had no exposure to it ever -- but I will try.  Also, please explain about `\let\path\relax` command. What did you 'relax' here?

Comment: @manucpp The `\let\path\relax` line is not necessary: `\DeclareUrlCommand` silently overwrites.

Comment: @manucpp -- To redefine a macro safely, it's usually best to "undefine" it first. One such way is to equate the macro via a `\let` statement to the primitive instruction `\relax`. As its name suggests, the `\relax` macro is set up to do nothing. (More precisely, whatever is being executed by TeX is stopped cold when `\relax` is encountered.) For more information on "undefining" a macro via the `\let` approach see, e.g., [@egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20678/5001) to the query [How to undo a \def (i.e., Need a \undef capability)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20655/5001).

Comment: @manucpp - As @egreg has commented in the meantime, the instruction `\let\path\relax` isn't strictly necessary here, as `\DeclareUrlCommand` is savvy enough to overwrite the existing definition of `\path`. Importantly, though,`\let\path\relax` doesn't hurt either. :-)