# Undefined control sequence \iftoggle

Tags: macros, conditionals, urls, etoolbox

As an extension to [file ended while scanning use of \path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315673/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-path), I tried using path with `\iftoggle` from `etoolbox` package.

Below is the error I get

> File ended while scanning use of \etb@tgl@BuildC.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{etoolbox, xcolor}

\let\path\relax \DeclareUrlCommand\path{\color{black!70}\urlstyle{tt}}

\newtoggle{BuildC}

\settoggle{BuildC}{true}

\begin{document}
    \iftoggle{BuildC}%
    {%
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item ABC
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Copy to \path{C:\Applications\}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{enumerate}
}%
{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item DEF
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Copy to \path{~/Applications/}
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

This happens only when I use `\path` within `\iftoggle`. The document compiles without errors if I remove `\path`.

**EDIT:**

Sorry about this edit. It changes things a lot. The MWE and the error has been updated to include file paths. This edit also prevents this question from being a duplicate.

Comment: It does not seem to have anything to do with `\iftoggle` but rather your use of `\color` in the new  definition of `\url`. You have not loaded any packages that provide color. Adding `xcolor` and your MWE compiles for me.

Comment: You still need `color` access in order to use `\color`! The main issue here is that `\path` seems to be interpreting `\}` in the ABC part. Removing the trailing ``\`` or using ``\ }`` and it compiles fine.

Comment: damn!! One of these days, I'm gonna need a paramedic to pry my foot outta my mouth.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue in the updated question is

1. You still ought to use `xcolor` in order for `\color` to work, else it is ignored
2. Using `\path` inside the argument to other commands may behave strangely. `\path{...\}` works outside macros but not inside. Here is a simpler example

   ```
   \newcommand\test[1]{#1}
   \test{\path{C:\Applications\}}
   ```

   fails with the same error.

   ```
    \test{\path{C:\Applications\ }}
   ```

   seems to work. So I'm guessing that the `\part` argument parsing is stumped by `\}` and thus the scanning for argument never ends.

Comment: Sorry about the edit...