# How can I make minted in newfloat mode work with dot2texi?

Tags: minted, compilation-error, dot2texi

The following gives a compilation error:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\begin{document}
Content
\end{document}
```

with output

```
...
Package: dot2texi 2008/05/07 v3.0p1 Run dot2tex from LaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moreverb/moreverb.sty
Package: moreverb 2008/06/03 v2.3a `more' verbatim facilities
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2019/11/10 v1.5r LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
...
Package: minted 2017/07/19 v2.5 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
...
! LaTeX Error: Command \listing already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1151 ...sting}{tbp}{lol}[\minted@float@within]}}
                                                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

It seems that `moreverb` and `minted` are both trying to define `\listing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `moreverb` defines `listing` and `listing*` environments that conflict with the environment with the same names defined by `minted`.

You can remove the useless environments defined by `moreverb`.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{dot2texi}
% remove the definitions of listing and listing*
\newcommand\zzzzzz[1]{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\relax}
\zzzzzz{listing}\zzzzzz{endlisting}
\zzzzzz{listing*}\zzzzzz{endlisting*}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}
Content
\end{document}
```

Note: I used a fairly large number of `z`'s in order to make David happy.

With no `z`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{dot2texi}
% remove the definitions of listing and listing*
\csundef{listing}\csundef{endlisting}
\csundef{listing*}\csundef{endlisting*}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}
Content
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\csundef` was exactly what I was looking for - I was expecting https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20655/41112 to mention it, but it seems not to.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer your `zzz` approach instead of `csundef`?

Comment: @Eric The `z` approach would make David happy, that's the main reason. Out of joke, it doesn't require loading an additional package.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me if I changed the order of the package declarations.
First, `moreverb` and later `minted`.

```
\usepackage{moreverb}

\usepackage{minted}
```